# What's the difference between import from 'events' vs. import {EventEmitter} from 'events'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, eventemitter

Seems both can work. the two `e1` listed below are both `EventEmitter`s and can be used that way.

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";
let e1 = new EventEmitter();
```

```
import events from "events";
let e1 = new events();
```

I googled and found no answers. I also researched node docs and found the the differences starts from node 4.x (at 0.12.x, it was still `import from Events.EventEmitter`).

Could anyone help explain what's the difference here?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_builtin_modules seems relevant.

Comment: "*`import from Events.EventEmitter`*"? node 4 and node 0.12 didn't have any support for ES6 modules. And `from Events.EventEmitter` is invalid anyway. What exactly do you refer to? Could you maybe link the pages you found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use curly braces `{ }` while importing from a module, You are directly importing  specific export from a module called **named exports** and not the whole module.

Modules can have a *default export* which can be imported without using the curly braces. `import MyModule from './MyModule` . This default export may give you access to other exports of the module depending how the module handles it's exports.

Comment: so are you saying the default export of "events" module IS events.EventEmitter?  and also curious there is no "Event" class builtin in node i guess? i wish node docs had explained in their docs. it's confusing for newbies...

Comment: btw for the following code, it doesn't look like the default export is EventEmitter. otherwise code below should break? (unless EventEmitter has a property called EventEmitter pointing to itself....)
=========



var events = require('events');
var eventCenter = new events.EventEmitter();

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js.    On line 49, ` EventEmitter. EventEmitter = EventEmitter; ` defines a property that point the object itself, So your code works.

Comment: And yes, there is no Event class in node. All the events are generated using EventEmitter.